# Using Qt Package Config Files on Windows?

Tags: c++, windows, qt, include-path, pkg-config

How do i use qt with package-config on widows? I can't find the folder with the qt package confiles ie QtCore.pc QtGui.pc etc. if they aren't distributed with the vs2010 binaries, how do i generate them? I would like to avoid rebuilding qt if possible. I am using Qt 4.8 with the default win32 visual studio 2010 binaries.

Comment: What Qt version are you talking about? 5.0?

Comment: Is the problem using Qt in general (that certain Qt files cant be found) or is it running the .exe version of your program and therefore not finding the files themselves? Or do you just want to know where they are in general?

Comment: I just would like to know where the qt pkg-config files aare in general or how to generate them so i can add the path to PKG_CONFIG_PATH. The library that i am trying to use (QtGstreamer) needs the qt pkg-config files.

Comment: At the moment I use cygwin Qt SDK (which means Qt creator), so it _might_ not be the same, but I can find the DLL files (which is what I really need to link to get the program working) in the qtsdk folder in C:. However I also found the pkg-config files in cygwin just by a normal search on the C drive. Sorry that I cannot give you a better answer than "Use the search function", but that is all I got. Good luck :)

Comment: i tried searching for QtCore.pc and QtGui.pc and no luck. I guess the pkg-config files aren't included in the visual studio build.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22949/discussion-between-jason123-and-john-mikael-gundersen)